# newly created folder does not show up in Windows explorer

Tags: android

I am creating my app folder /Android/data/com.mycompany.myapp. It is empty at first. However it is not visible in Windows explorer. Doing this solves it:

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```

Unfortunately this is no longer supported in API 19 (4.4). What is the alternative?

For Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE I need to specify a file, not a folder. The same is true for MediaScannerConnection.scanFile...

Comment: Add your solution as an answer and accept it so that others can see it more easily.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I implemented this work-around:

1. create the desired folder
2. create an empty "dummy" file in this folder
3. announce this file to the media scanner with:

   ```
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("file://" + m_appDir + "/tmp.x");
    sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, uri));
   ```

This will make the file and the folder visible from Windows.

Comment: This is an answer as dirty as it is correct :) anyone has an idea how to find out when it is possible to delete the file `tmp.x`? If you delete it right after the sendBroadcast, it is of course too soon for the broadcasted intents to detect the folder. Yes, I just want to keep the directory clean... :) (and avoid my users to keep asking me what is that file)

Comment: One could listen to `ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_STARTED` and `ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_FINISHED` to know when to delete the dummy file. But that's a bit expensive to simply create a folder...